# Sed Capturing Repeating Number Groups

Tags: bash, macos, unix, sed

I am trying to use sed to capture a group like these examples:

```
123123 (i would want the first group 123)
144144 (I would want the group 144)
```

however sed does not seem to realize what \1 is.

Is there any way to do this using sed? I want to replace the first group with a specific string afterwards.

```
([0-9]+)\1
```

I have tried using the above regex yet, sed does not seem to realize what I am trying to do.

also tried this:

```
~/Desktop$ cat file
123123
23231
12323
123231
12345
144144
~/Desktop$ sed -n 's/.*\b\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)\1\b.*/\1/p' file
~/Desktop$ 

~/Desktop$ sed -n -E 's/([0-9]+)\1/specificstring\1/p' file
specificstring12323
specificstring2323
specificstring12323
specificstring14444

~/Desktop$ sed -nE 's/^([0-9]+)\1([^0-9]|$)/\1/p' file
2323
12323
```

Comment: What exactly does `sed` emit?  How exactly do you invoke `sed`?

Comment: What if there are no groups in a line? Please post a few sample lines from the sample.  See [mcve]

Comment: sed was emitting just the number 1 for both examples, if there are no groups in a line it should emit the whole entire sequence of numbers 

so if its 123456 i would want it to emit 123456

Comment: yeah i install GNU sed and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a BRE, and avoid using `+` since it is not a part of POSIX REs.

```
$ cat file
123123
23231
12323
123231
12345
144144
$ 
$ sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\1$/\1/p' file
123
144
```

Comment: this actually works the best on mac from what i can see. Ill have to give you the accepted answer for actually getting it to work on OSX

Comment: @A.Hill thanks, but anyways install GNU sed and stick with it.

Comment: Right this is what you need to do to get it to work with MacOS/BSD sed since backreferences don't work when you enable EREs with `-E` in that sed but they do work when it's run without that option. Installing GNU sed was the right thing to do, you should install GNU awk while you're at it!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to replace the first group with a specific string afterwards.

With `GNU sed` :

```
sed -n -E 's/([0-9]+)\1/specificstring\1/p' file
```

**Takeaways**

- `-n` suppresses the output which we override using the  print (`p` ) flag of the `s` command.
- `-E` enables extended regular expressions.

<sup>**Note**
This doesn't, however, print the lines where there no identical groups the existence of which is not mentioned in the question.</sup>

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you, I have seen your  comment above. Changed already.

Comment: this outputs the following:
  echo 144144 | sed -n -E 's/([0-9]+)\1/specificstring\1/p'
specificstring14444

Comment: @A.Hill Sorry but I can't reproduce that in my Linux box. It is giving me the right result.

Comment: yeah im on a mac... unsure why its different or how i can make it the same

Answer (score 1):

Given that the file only contains 6 digit numbers and nothing else it could be done like this:

```
sed -n 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\1/\1/p' file
```

Comment: Edit: didnt realize formatting didnt work I updated the question

Comment: @A.Hill which version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: macOSX doesnt have a --version option for sed but im using the sed that comes preinstalled on mac if that helps.

Comment: @A.Hill I've added a posix version

Comment: It wont work with Mac/BSD sed since that version doesn't support backreferences in the regexp.

Comment: -E is a gnu extension

Comment: @oguzismail -`E` is supported on Mac/BSD sed too which is why it's better to use that than `-r` which IS GNU only. Yes, it's non-POSIX. For POSIX you need to do all that escaping BS to enable RE metachars.

Comment: but still, it's non-POSIX

Comment: @oguzismail :) I run `sed --posix -E ...` but looks you are right

Comment: yeah that still outputted something but not the desired outcome (it didnt catch 144144 or 123123) actually.. im not entirely sure what that POSIX version IS trying to catch.

Comment: @A.Hill can you please edit your question to include expected output for hek2mgl's example

Comment: @oguz ismail expected output is the same as the beginning I jsut want group one, but I will edit to show what it did output

Comment: @A.Hill Do you only have numbers in that file? I mean from beginning to the end of the line? no other characters? That would simplify it

Comment: no spaces are there only enters if thats what you are asking @hek2mgl

Comment: Ok, let's try the simple command which I posted now. I would be surprised if that doesn't work

Comment: this also can be an answer if in the future everything is sticking to 6 digits, kind of dangerous to have something specific like that.